# How to click a button into a list array items only effect the related item using React hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Here's the issue I faced, when I got 2 item-lists, if I click one button of them, both of the buttons will be triggered and do duplicate queries, I know there's a way to pass the objectId of the key to link the query, but I don't know how to achieve that in this situation with react hooks.

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react'

//click button will popup modal
function Test(){

  const [data, setData] = useState([])
  const open = useCallback(async ()=>{

      const result = await = axios.post(
        Url,
        { source: 'data'},
        {
          headers: header,
        }
      );
      setData(result.data);
  }, [])

return(   

          <div>

            {data == null
              ? " "
              : data.map((i) => (

                          <List>
                            <ListItem>
                        <button onClick={open} key={i.objectId} >
                          button
                        </button>
                              {i.name}
                            </ListItem>
                          </List>

             )}
         </div>
)
}

export default Test
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a open method on your button onClick.You will get an event object in your useCallback method.You can use it to prevent both buttons triggering.You can use e.stopPropagation() method.

```
 const open = useCallback(async (event)=>{

 event.stopPropagation();

  const result = await = axios.post(
    Url,
    { source: 'data'},
    {
      headers: header,
    }
  );
  setData(result.data);
  }, [])
```

Comment: It's not working, I think that's not about bubble issue, the logic here is when data include 2 names, I'll get 2 list-items, and in this time I only want to trigger one of the items instead of duplication trigger another one.